# How to make configure eclipse with Hibernate

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

How to make configure eclipse IDE with hibernate.
When I click windows -> Open Perspective -> Others It does not list out Hibernate.
Can you tel me how to make configure hibernate with the same.

T.Saravanan

Answer (score 0):

Under the 'Help' menu you will find an 'Install New Software'.  Basically you need to install a plugin that supports hibernate development.  hibernate tools is a good place to start:
http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html